# SourceTree - Git Rebase resulting in automatic merge

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I'm using SourceTree 1.9.10.0 on Windows 10 and I wan't to rebase my feature branch EUR-1058 onto master. I do it like this:

[image]

This results in the following tree:

[image]

And If I do a pull an automatic merge happens:

[image]

Why is this happening? Is it due to the fact that the commit "Mailcheck rewrite" was on my laptop and I'm now rebaseing from my desktop and the SHA-1 hashes has somehow changed or something similar?

Comment: Your language is confusing.  Rebase "onto" is a specific thing, and not what you are doing.  Are you trying to rebase `feature` on `master`, or vice-versa?  As for the automatic merge, the default for your pull in SourceTree is probably to merge, hence you got a merge.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen EUR-1058 on master. In SourceTree the title says `Rebase current changes onto master`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you rebased your `EUR-1058` branch on `master`, you *rewrote* the history of that branch.  Consider the following diagram illustrating the point:

```
master:   ...A -- B ---- C -- D
                   \
EUR-1058:           E -- F
```

Rebasing `EUR-1058` on `master` means doing the following steps:

- rolling the branch back to the commit from which it branched off `master`, in this case commit `B`
- then replaying the commits from `master` on top of `B`, in this case replaying commits `C` and `D`
- finally, reapplying the commits you made to `EUR-1058` since commit `B`, i.e. commits `E` and `F`

After rebasing, the diagram looks like this:

```
master:   ...A -- B ---- C -- D
                               \
EUR-1058:                       E' -- F'
```

Note that I have labelled `E'` and `F'`, to indicate that these are in fact *new* commits, which were made during the rebase.

Now to answer your actual question, when you tried to do a `git pull` on `EUR-1058`, Git first checked to see if your local branch could be fast-forwarded by what is on the remote (or in `origin/EUR-1058`).  In this case, no fast-forward was possible.  Git views the remote branch at this point as being totally different than what you have locally.  Hence, it completed the pull by making a merge commit.

What you probably should have done is to force push your rebased `EUR-1058` branch to the remote after completing the rebase via:

```
git push --force EUR-1058
```

Using force is necessary here because the history/base of the branch has changed.  This is the same reason why you ended up with a merge commit.  After the force push, you can continue life as normal.

As a word of caution, you should realize that rewriting the history of `EUR-1058` can cause problems for anyone sharing this branch.  So, it should be done carefully.